# Rename files using regex in linux

Tags: linux

Hi I need to change these filenames in a folder:

```
dingo__AAA311P02_2845__L7_ACTTGA_L007_R1_001.fastq.gz
lala_bros__AAA000M11_3289__L2_ACTGAT_L002_R2_001.fastq.gz
nice__AAA827M10_2860__L7_ACTGAT_L007_R2_001.fastq.gz
```

I need to retain the AAA****** (eg. AAA255P02) and also keep the R1 or R2 and the extension fastq.gz

So ideally i would like to get these:
`AAA311P02_R1.fastq.gz
AAA000M11_R2.fastq.gz
AAA827M10_R2.fastq.gz`

I tried using 
`rename 's/^.*\(AAA[1-9][1-9][1-9][A-Z][1-9][1-9]\).*$/\$1/g' *.fastq.gz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\(...\)` searches for parenthesis but does not capture its contents.

I see three blocks to get captured, so I'd propose the following:

```
rename 's/^.*(AAA.{6}).*(_R.).*(\.fastq.gz)/$1$2$3/' *.fastq.gz
```

1st block: `AAA` followed by six characters.

2nd block: `_R` followed by a single character.

3rd block: the extension `.fastq.gz`